# Message recovery in JBoss Messaging

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jboss-messaging

We're having a lot of problems with our setup featuring Java 6, JBoss Application Server 5.1.0.GA and JBoss Messaging 1.4.6.GA. Lately there have been a string of server crashes(caused by me and my colleages :-) ) and that has left us with some messages in an inconsistent state(not properly delivered). Normally the JBoss Messaging recovery manager should take care of those scenarios upon server reboot as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/userguide-1.4.0.GA/html/recovery.html). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering is there a manual way to recover problematic messages or maybe some other alternative to the JBoss Messaging Recovery manager?

Thanks in advance for your help!